Windows->Preferences-> Validation missing in Spring Tool Suite 4
Screenshot
Can you help me how to show the Validation under Windows->Preferences in Spring Tool Suite 4? I tried copy org.eclipse.wst.validation_1.3.0.v202308161955.jar and org.eclipse.wst.validation.ui_1.3.100.v202405020134.jar to plugin folder but it is still not showing.

I'm having the same issue. The preference pages are just gone, as well as the context menus that e.g. allowed you to manually trigger validation.

Which validations specifically are you looking for? In Eclipse, you can't just copy JARs into the plugins folder. You have to install features via the "Install New Software" menu item instead, e.g. the Web Tools features from the main Eclipse update site (in case those are the validations you are looking for).
